# How to return an array object without NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Declared:

```
private Man[] man;
```

This is the initialization:

```
Man[] man = new Man[1];

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        man[i] = new Man();
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                man[i].eatThis(table.foods[table.topFood-1]);
                table.topFood--;
            }
    }
```

Want to print this:

```
System.out.println(getMan(0));
```

which goes to:

```
public Man getMan(int k){
 return man[k];
}
```

but I receive NullPointerException. Why? While:

```
System.out.println(man[0]);
```

works just fine.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at ManRunning.getMan(ManRunning.java:80)
at ManRunning.newGame(ManRunning.java:133)
at ManRunning.<init>(ManRunning.java:57)
at RunDevilRun.main(RunDevilRun.java:9)
```

Comment: Which variable is not initialized when you get to the line in question? Use a debugger and set a breakpoint nearby, and step through to determine the answer.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html

Comment: It is hard to give an answer with limited information, can you provide the initialization of the variables used?

Comment: Please post the full code and the error stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the line (1)

```
Man[] man = new Man[1];
```

is hiding the instance variable declared in this line (2)

```
private Man[] man;
```

any decent IDE would show a warning for this.

here is how you should initialize the array man in the line (1) declared with line (2)

```
man = new Man[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Obivously you have two `man` array variables, one that is initialized and one (a member variable) that isn't.

Comment: Could you please show me those mans? One is in method and other one that is initialized as man[i] = new Man()? How can I point to one correct man?

Comment: `private Man[] man;` is instance variable hidden by local variable `Man[] man = new Man[1];` the man you are accessing in getMan(int) is not initialized.